# NetBeans не создается (открывается) проект

Tags: netbeans, windows-10, java

Установил netbeans 8.2 и jdk 9
Не создаются проекты, а также не открываются существующие.
OC: Windows 10 x64

Answer (score 2):

я удалил jdk 9 и поставил jdk 8. Заработало.

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans 8.2 поддерживает версию не выше 1.8

Answer (score 0):

У меня стояли разные вариант JDK, когда переключил на 8 тоже заработало. Команда переключения версии:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```